# celltable - howto use an image as celltable background (or row background)

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable, celltable, gwt-celltable

I need to use an image as table background (as entire row background will works).
I tried this:

```
.cellTableOddRow {
    background-image: url(image.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    width: 300px;
}
```

but it puts the image in each cell.
Is this possible?

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It was really simple:

The image should be in 'cellTableWidget'

```
.cellTableWidget {
    background-image: url(../img/bgtablas.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    width: 300px;
}
```

and the row must to 'delete' its style:

```
.cellTableOddRow {
    background: none;
    background-image: none;
}
```